# What is the name of this kind of forms?

Tags: android-layout

I need to add a form exactly like this to my app, but I cannot find information because I do not know how do they are "called".

Form is like this:

[image]

Comment: TextView as Title, 2x EditTexts and two buttons without borders

Comment: Yeah, I know but it is attached to the toolbar or something like that? It has a back button.

Comment: wlan title  has match_parent with bottom line. No it's not atached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault, I attached the action bar to the activity and it shows exactly as the picture.